# HP QTD - ImportSheet with only some columns

Tags: qtp, import-from-excel

I have my Test in HP QTD that imports sheet from Excel.
The code imports all columns in the sheet:

```
DataTable.ImportSheet("myFile.xls", "Plan1", "Dest")
```

But myFile.xls has more than 200 columns, and I need only 6.

Is there a way to import only the columns thah I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar kind of question was answered earlier,see if the following link helps.

[How to import data from excel to UFT based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740963/how-to-import-data-from-excel-to-uft-based-on-condition)